# Mac OSX 10.6.8が起動できない。

Tags: macos

お世話になります。表題の通りなのですが、Mac OSX 10.6.8が起動できなくなりました。原因はHDDエラーで修復が必要な状態になっております。
インストールDVDがない状態だったのでyosemiteのインストーラーを入れて、再起動後にインストーラーを起動しユーティリティーでの修復を試みましたが、修復ボタンがグレーアウトしたままで修復作業ができませんでした。同様に消去も試みましたがアンマウントできないとの警告と共に消去も不可能でした。
PC自体は生きていいるので、何とかならないかいろいろ試してはいるのですが、現在再起動をかけるとインストーラーが立ち上がってしまい、PCから立ち上げることができません。CDやDVDから起動する方法はいろいろあるかと思いますが、PCから強制的に立ち上げるにはどのようにすればよいでしょうか？
最終的にはHDDを修復してHDDをフォーマットしてきれいな状態にしたいと思っています。
何かしら詳しい方いましたら、ご教授お願いします。

ターミナルから何らかの処置をした方がよいでしょうか。。。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 率直に言って、物理的な寿命という線はありませんか？Mac自体はいつのモデルでしょうか。

Comment: 「物理的な寿命」というおおざっぱなことはいう気はありませんが、おそらくハードディスクは壊れていて、交換するしかないでしょう。とりあえず、ハードディスクの交換を検討してください。それから、この手の質問では、Macの機種名、型番の情報は必須なので、それらなしで有効な回答が得られるとは、考えないでください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。おそらく、その可能性が非常に高いです。

Macの情報で今しがたわかっているのはこんな感じになります。

機種名: iMac
機種ID: iMac11,3
プロセッサ名: Intel Core i3
プロセッサ速度: 3.2GHz
プロセッサ個数: 1
コアの総数: 2
二次キャッシュ（コア単位）: 256 KB
三次キャッシュ: 4MB
メモリ: 8GB
OS: Mac OS X 10.6.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

そのiMacの型番は、MC510J/A、「iMac 27inch Mid 2010」といったほうが通じやすいかもしれません。
内部にアクセスするには、フロントパネルを外し、液晶を取り出さないといけない構造になっています。かなり習熟した者でなければ、ハードディスクの交換はむずかしいでしょう。へたに手を出すと、壊れてない箇所を壊してしまう確率が、高すぎます。いちどAppleのサポートに連絡を取って、ハードディスク交換の見積もりを出してもらったらどうでしょう？
ハードディスクが壊れていない可能性に、一縷の望みをお持ちになるのでしたら、「ディスクユーティリティ」で認識しないデバイスは、ほかのソフトウェアを使っても、認識しないとだけ、アドバイスさしあげておきます。
では、私だったらどうするかというと、さすがに27インチディスプレイを使えないのは、もったいありませんから、USB接続の外付けハードディスクを調達して、それにOSをインストールして、起動ディスクにして、iMacを使用することを考えます。Macは、外付けのディスクからブートできるんです。
さすがに、USBの転送速度がボトルネックになって、とくに起動時間が遅くなってしまいますが、ネットブラウズや、文書作成程度の作業に不満はない程度は、期待できます。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
なるほどなるほど。そういうことができるんですね。
まずはAppleサポートで見積もりをとってみました。近所のAppleストアでは50000円が修理の最低見積もりになって+20000から30000で修理、更にHDDの実費で10万近くになるそうです。そうなるとあと数万だして
新しいものを買った方が良さそうな感じもしないでもないです。

HDDの交換を自分でやるのは、WindowsやLinuxではごく頻繁にやっておりますが、Macは初めてです。これはちょっと敷居が高いかなと自分でも思っています。

外付けHDDでブートする方法、ありがとうございます。こちら是非挑戦してみます。というのも私は仕事的にはコマンドラインが殆どで、ブラウズは制作物のチェックや簡単なコーディングだけなので、殆ど問題ないと思っています。
貴重な情報ありがとうございます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。本日TOSHIBAの外付けHDDを購入してOSXインストールして無事復活しました。また起動ディスクから元々調子の悪かった内蔵HDDを初期化してみましたら成功しました。こちらも偶然ではありますがとてもよかったです。
修復成功しましたが、元のディスクに再インストールするのも面倒なので、このまましばらく使おうと思います。正直全く速度が落ちた感じがしないし、内蔵ディスクと遜色ない感じです。
アドバイスありがとうございました！

Comment: @osamuya問題が解決したら、質問を閉じてください。クローズのしかたは、ヘルプにのっているはず。では、27インチのiMacを大事にしてあげてくださいませ。

Comment: すみません。ありがとうございます。おかげ様でiMac快適に動いております。スレットすっかり閉じ忘れておりました。今後ともよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: すみません。質問のクローズの方法がわからず。。です。クローズに反対するという項目はあるのですが、クローズそのものの方法がどうにも見つかりません。どなたかおしえてください。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 正確には、クローズをする方法はなく、質問者は、いちばん役だった回答を「承認する」だけです。緑色のチェックマークを回答につけることで、承認とします。正しい表現をすべきでした。すみません。

Comment: こちらこそありがとうございます！